# Does exist a control like a FlipView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, itemscontrol

I have used FlipView from Metro Applications and that's what I'm trying to looking for. To have an items control but only show one of them.

I'm looking for a similiar control like the FlipView but in WPF.

I have reached but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at following article -

[Quickstart: Animating your UI (Metro style apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx)

I think they did something like what you want.

using `silverlight` or `wpf`